# How do I get a 3D building added to Google Earth / Maps?

Tags: google-earth, google-maps

I noticed that there wasn't a 3D model available for a particular location on Google Earth. I know how this building looks, so how would I contribute by making a model of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building Maker is a great tool, but only available in a limited set of areas. However, you can download Google SketchUp to make any 3D models, including buildings for Google Earth. You'll need to upload geo-located models to the 3D Warehouse for review and publishing. See the [geo-modeling section](http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167459) of SketchUp's Help Center.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check out:

- [Google's Building Maker: Create 3D buildings online](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwh/buildingmaker.html)

> Building Maker is a 3D modeling tool for adding buildings to Google Earth. It's fun to use, and an easy way to get on the 3D map. Here's how it works:
>
> - Select a city from around the world.
> - Make a building with photos we provide.
> - Save your building and it will be reviewed.
> - See your 3D building in Google Earth!

Answer (score 2):

Three basic options:

1. Use building maker and do it yourself (learning curve, lower quality model)
2. Use Sketchup and do it yourself (bigger learning curve, high quality model)
3. Get a [3D buildings](http://www.estate3d.com) service to do it for you (costs money but no hassle)